# Two rows of text inside a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

How to write text in two rows inside a JLabel ( It doesn't work with `\n` ) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two or more lines in a JTable cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569092/two-or-more-lines-in-a-jtable-cell)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newline in JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090098/newline-in-jlabel)

Comment: @Jigar Joshi, that one is not an exact duplicate, since the asker did not know that the table cell renderer was a JLabel but this question is specific to JLabel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to make it like this: 
`JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("<html>this is line1<br>this is line2</html>");`

Answer (score 6):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Two<br/>lines</html>");
```

See [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Comment: I did not realize it was covered in the Java tutorial!  Note though - that example page as well as most here, do not omit the unnecessary closing </html> element.  Since it is invalid HTML in any case (no <body> element), it makes little sense to add the closing </html> element.  On that link - another point is that it would be nice to see a list of the entire set of elements that the Swing components can render.  It is basically HTML 3.2, but not all of it.  Also the Swing rendering engine generally handles a variety of CSS, but undocumented, AFAIU. :(

Comment: Re the CSS support in last comment, meant to say more along the lines of "..but (which exact parts of CSS are supported is) undocumented,..".  And while I'm here, another correction on the Java Tutorial page.  While the *first* example closes the </html>, the later examples do not.

Answer (score 2):

go for `"<html> one <br/> two </html>"`

Answer (score 2):

```
jLabel.add("<html>a<br/>b</html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is also solution if you want to center the two lines in the jlabel.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html> <center> line1 </center> <center> line2 </center> </html>");
```